# can't receive attached file in contact form 7 plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload, plugins, contact-form-7

thanks for your time in advance.
i create a form with contact  form 7 plugin , its work fine and send the email but it don't attach the files. here is my codes and I'm sure my mail config is ok:
file upload tags:
[file file-826 limit:20000000 filetypes:mp4 id:apply_film_btn class:apply_film_btn]

[file file-825 limit:2000000 filetypes:zip|rar|doc|pdf id:apply_resume_btn class:apply_resume_btn]

i add these to File attachments:[file-825][file-826]
i tried change the path to another folder so i put this line to wp-config:

```
define( 'WPCF7_UPLOADS_TMP_DIR', '/home/synapsea/domains/synapseaccelerator.com/public_html/wp-content/uploads/email-att' );
```

and create the folder and also change the that folder and parent folders permission to 777 in my direct admin.
i tried CFDB7 plugin and it didn't solve the problem.

when I try to submit the form it doesn't take the time to upload file and send the email immediately.i receive the mail but without attached file

here is my form : https://synapseaccelerator.com/apply/
I'm using WordPress Version 5.8.2 & CF7 Version 5.5.3

Comment: I have tested CF7 with custom dir and its working fine. Maybe your hosting is blocking the attachment for some reason ? Try using WP Mail SMTP

Comment: Did you check with the default contact form 7 upload directory?
Without define the WPCF7_UPLOADS_TMP_DIR.

Comment: yes it didn't work , i change the htaccess file too! same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:
I wrapped my short code with form tag ! like this:

```
 <form class="mb-5" method="post" id="contactForm" name="contactForm">
<?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="268" title="apply form 1 farsi"]'); ?>
 </form>
```

i just remove the form tag and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

The first idea I have is to check the `www-data` user permissions to ensure it has access and privilege to create and overwrite files in your directory (assuming that you're using Ubuntu), e.g.:

```
chgrp www-data /home/your_directory
chmod g+rwxs /home/your_directory
```

You can find more details about granting permissions to `www-data` [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244406/how-do-i-give-www-data-user-to-a-folder-in-my-home-folder)

Comment: thank you for your comment i already give write and read permission in my direct admin :(